# calculating max value ocurrance for each row formula in excel

Tags: excel

```
A      B

1      4
2      5
3      6
100    7
1000   8
```

how can find number of max value of column values for each row.
=COUNTIF(A1:B5,A1:A5) trying this but this gives 0. I expected 2.

Since; 100 and 1000 are the max values of their rows. need only max value times for rows for A

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? why `2`? I do not see anywhere in your data where the data duplicates.

Comment: @ScottCraner bro I am trying to find max values for all rows of A. only 100 and 1000 are the max values

Comment: What determines the max value? the only true max (the maximum value) is 1000.  100 is less than 1000 and therefor not the max value. bro.

Comment: You should just use =MAX(A1:A5) to get the max value in Column A.

Comment: @Piyush I dont interst actual data only need how many times it is

Comment: @ScottCraner dude I calculate max for each row.. For A column only 4th(100) and 5th(1000) are max values so I expect formula output 2

Comment: It will require a helper column in C to hold the max between the two, then you can use `=SUM(COUNTIF(A:A,C1:C5))` as an array formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the ways you can do it.

[image]

Should give you **2**.

Comment: Normal operation is to have the formulas in the text so it can be copied and pasted with a photo to back up.